# Window minimizing broken after building QT app with Mac OS High Sierra SDK

Tags: c++, macos, qt, minimize

I have a frameless Qt app setup with `setWindowFlags (Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` and custom minimize and close buttons.
I'm having trouble minimizing the app by using `setWindowState (Qt::WindowState::WindowMinimized)` or `showMinimized()` and the 10.13 SDK. It worked fine on Mac with the 10.12 SDK.
I also tested this with a new clean project with no special eventFilters or similar. Anyone else with this problem? I'm using Qt 5.10.0, this problem also appeared in Qt 5.9.1.

I'm just doing this in my MainWindow which works with the 10.12 SDK.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        QPushButton* minimizeButton = new QPushButton(this);
        minimizeButton->setText(QLatin1String("Minimize"));
        connect(minimizeButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QMainWindow::showMinimized);
    }
```

Comment: Are there any messages for your app on the console?

Comment: nothing, I'm afraid.

Comment: edited my code after I setup a testing app where I don't get any console output